# Changing NumberConstants.decimalSeparator() value

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm working with NumberField and NumberFormat.
How can I change NumberConstants.decimalSeparator() value without changing my locale? For instance I want to have "." or "," as decimal separators for all locales.
Is it possible to create custom property file NumberConstants_bla.properties and force gxt use it instead of standard NumberConstants_ru_RU.properties or NumberConstants_en_US.properties (depending on current locale)? Where should I place this file to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can set the decimal separator using [DecimalFormatSymbols](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html).

```
// default symbols for the locale
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
// set your required separator
decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
// create a decimal format and set your symbols
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
```

Comment: Infortunatly it's not an option for com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat :(

Comment: Ah just noticed the GWT tag. No experience there so can't suggest anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own NumberConstants (In which you put the decimal separator you want) then use it to create your own NumberFormat.

Example of my own NumberConstants:

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.constants.NumberConstants;

public class MyNumberConstants implements NumberConstants {
  @Override
  public String notANumber() {
    return "NaN";
  }

  @Override
  public String currencyPattern() {
    return "#,##0.00\\u00A0\\u00A4";
  }

  @Override
  public String decimalPattern() {
    return "#,##0.###";
  }

  @Override
  public String decimalSeparator() {
    return ".";
  }

  @Override
  public String defCurrencyCode() {
    return "EUR";
  }

  @Override
  public String exponentialSymbol() {
    return "e";
  }

  @Override
  public String globalCurrencyPattern() {
    return "#,##0.00\\u00A0\\u00A4";
  }

  @Override
  public String groupingSeparator() {
    return "\\u00A0";
  }

  @Override
  public String infinity() {
    return "\u221E";
  }

  @Override
  public String minusSign() {
    return "-";
  }

  @Override
  public String monetaryGroupingSeparator() {
    return ",";
  }

  @Override
  public String monetarySeparator() {
    return "\\u00A0";
  }

  @Override
  public String percent() {
    return "%";
  }

  @Override
  public String percentPattern() {
    return "#,##0\\u00A0%";
  }

  @Override
  public String perMill() {
    return "\\u2030";
  }

  @Override
  public String plusSign() {
    return "+";
  }

  @Override
  public String scientificPattern() {
    return "#E0";
  }

  @Override
  public String simpleCurrencyPattern() {
    return "#,##0.00\\u00A0\\u00A4";
  }

  @Override
  public String zeroDigit() {
    return "0";
  }
}
```

Example of MyFormat:

```
public class MyFormat extends NumberFormat{

  public MyFormat(){
    super(new MyNumberConstants(),"0.0", CurrencyList.get().getDefault(),true);
  }
}
```

Warning : this is an ugly workaround and could cause problems for i18n. I use it just to format some dimension which I assume to be displayed in the same way for everyone.